# Mark occurrences for JSP and Scriptlets is not working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, scriptlet

I am not able to highlight the matching variables in JSP and scriptlets. I have already tried
`Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Mark Occurrences`
and
`Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations`.
These are not working.

Is there any way I can highlight the matching variables in JSP and scriplets?

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Thanks & Regards,
Archana

Answer (score 1):

It appears that JSP files are opened in Eclipse using their own 'editor' distinct from the Java editor. Its settings are located under *Window -> Preferences -> Web -> JSP Files -> Editor*, but unfortunately it appears to lack the 'mark occurrences' feature found in the editors for [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919614/eclipse-doesnt-highlight-references-anymore) and some other languages.

There's an answer to another question on here with information on [how to implement 'mark occurrences'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038584/implement-mark-occurrences-in-new-eclipse-editor#7038776) in an editor (pointing to [Source viewers and annotations](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors_annotations.htm) in the Eclipse developers guide), but I couldn't even find a [bug in the Eclipse JSP 'product'](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?product=JSP&query_format=advanced) requesting the feature. It's open-source, though, so of course anyone is welcome to [contribute](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jeetools/webtools.javaee.git/) that functionality!

It doesn't accomplish quite the same thing (lacking the intelligence to restrict scope), but you can get a rough approximation of this functionality by selecting your variable/method/text and using the generic *Source -> Occurrences in File* feature.